# How to add basic authentication to a Axis2 service?

Tags: java, service, apache-axis, basic-authentication

I created a service with wsdl2java from Axis2 and I want to add HTTP basic authentication.

I read [this](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/axis2config.html#Global_Configuration) document and [this](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html) document from Axis2 home page but it doesn't seem to explain the server configuration. How can I configure basic authentication on server side?

Comment: Authentication for your web application is not Axis2 specific, and can be achieved through several different means. Widen the scope of your research to "securing Java web applications with BASIC authentication" and see what you find.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally host my webservices using a web server (nginx/apache) and/or a app server (tomcat) and configure the basic authentication there. You get better control, logging and monitoring options this way. Specially if you want to authenticate against a database, LDAP or active directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use embeded Jetty and I deployed Axis2 war.

I added basic authentication to Jetty using the example from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/embedded-examples.html#embedded-secured-hello-handler) with 2 small changes:

- user and password are passed directly in the code like this:

> loginService.putUser("username", Credential.getCredential("password"),
>   new String[] {"user"});

- the line

> mapping.setPathSpec("/*");

is changed to match only my service web path so user and password will not be required for the rest of the axis interface.